# To change mat-input placeholder (Floating label) styles on focus

Tags: css, angular-material2

I need to apply padding-top/margin-top to placeholder of "mat-input" on focus. I also tried to debug on focus, but it seems Angular material is not showing the styles on focus.

```
::ng-deep .mat-focused .mat-form-field-label {
      margin-top: 6px !important;
    }
```

Comment: what does not work:https://i.stack.imgur.com/MHhxA.png see stackblitz:https://stackblitz.com/edit/mat-input-mat-error-mat-form-field-wlqq49?file=app/input-overview-example.css

Comment: I had put the block inside .mat-form-field. That's the reason it was not working. Removed it. It's working. Thanks.